# Как добавить свойство в класс которое возвращает колличество товаров в корзину

Tags: c#, linq

Итак, у нас есть класс Product, описывающий товар:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public Product(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Мы хотим реализовать функционал корзины. В корзине у нас есть позиции BasketPosition. В каждой позиции храним какой продукт был добавлен в корзину (свойство Product) и в каком количестве (свойство Amount):

public class BasketPosition

```
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public BasketPosition(Product product, int amount)
    {
        Product = product;
        Amount = amount;
    }
}
```

А теперь опишем саму корзину Basket. В ней будем хранить ее идентификатор (свойство Id) и список позиций (свойство Positions):

```
public class Basket

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<BasketPosition> Positions { get; set; }

    public Basket(int id, List<BasketPosition> positions)
    {
        Id = id;
        Positions = positions;
    }
}
```

Нужно добавить get only свойство ProductsAmount, которое возвращает общее количество продуктов в корзине.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать такое свойство в классе Basket. Я так понимаю оно должно возвращать int - колличество товаров в корзине, но к чему я должен обратиться в getere чтобы мне стала доступна информация по Amount

Comment: хм, приложение для одного юзера что ли? или почему нет юзер_айди для идентификации чья это корзина?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в корзине товар, у которого есть поле "Количество"
В корзине следует добавить поле:

```
  int TotalAmount
    {
        get
        {
              return Positions.Sum(p => p.Amount);
        }
    }
```

Ошибся с подсчетом, при Count Получите количество позиций.
через Sum, общее количество товаров

Тогда при обращении к полю TotalAmoun будет подсчитано количество всех товаров в корзине